# Overlapping Bootstrap grids on mobile device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am fairly new to web design and trying to create a responsive page using the Bootstrap grid system. This is a simplified version of a page I am having problems with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">

        body, html {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        section {
            height: 100%;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }

    </style>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Section 1</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        <p>Ex suscipit laborum velit atque, eaque dolorum sequi, eligendi laudantium fuga quos dolorem officia sunt totam. Quidem aspernatur vero vitae laborum quaerat dolorum. Consequatur a tempora adipisci qui enim doloribus sequi voluptate, quidem itaque tenetur aut voluptas obcaecati adipisci architecto beatae aliquam? Nemo cumque sequi accusamus nesciunt obcaecati id blanditiis, neque laborum tenetur eveniet, rerum enim voluptatem voluptate itaque eos ut sint officiis molestiae?</p>
                        <p>Voluptate quis suscipit qui optio nulla unde veniam sed tempore itaque? Expedita optio amet, facere quia at consequatur reiciendis aperiam alias doloremque amet laudantium hic sunt, nulla voluptatem libero id veritatis molestiae ab in, totam dignissimos facere, accusantium voluptates mollitia quae iusto voluptas assumenda temporibus vel quod? Vero ipsa dolore impedit, animi laboriosam expedita similique impedit necessitatibus, repellat distinctio nobis amet voluptatem quae, expedita voluptas rerum?</p>
                        <p>Ratione aliquid deleniti maxime dicta, fugit incidunt quam omnis ad maiores, blanditiis modi repellat cumque ut nemo. Sapiente sequi sint, illum fugiat eum non deserunt totam doloremque officiis, alias fugiat asperiores doloremque laudantium numquam iste, tempore illum rem quidem.</p>
                        <p>Quam eum quia pariatur accusantium nesciunt, earum ducimus cupiditate doloribus voluptate fugiat reprehenderit esse obcaecati ex, corrupti dignissimos deserunt molestias tenetur minus, nam cum quaerat quidem, exercitationem iure ipsa vero neque quod iusto necessitatibus illo eos alias? Quae rem officiis accusantium ad expedita ratione modi tenetur reiciendis sint odio, eum animi voluptatem doloremque rem totam, sunt velit nobis blanditiis assumenda vel atque cupiditate nulla quo alias, sequi ullam nam deserunt eius labore nostrum hic tempore asperiores, dolorem repellendus expedita vel sit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Section 2</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Temporibus tempore dignissimos quaerat quo quisquam delectus commodi nesciunt sed.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

This looks fine on a desktop browser. However, when I view it on a mobile device browser (emulated iPhone 5 using Chromium), section 2 seems to overlap with section 1, as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: For smaller devices you need to use `col-sm-*` or `col-xs-*`, here's the bootstrap documentation that explains it http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `height` attribute from your `section` CSS and it will work.

## [Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/OBEjYCoQL9)

However, as @ChrisYongchu mentioned, the way you are currently formatting your HTML, there will be nothing responsive about your code. The sections will simply take up 100% of the width of the container at all screen sizes. One way to utilize Bootstrap correctly would be to have the content use 2 columns on large screen sizes and then stack on smaller screen sizes, the markup would look like this:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h1>Section 1</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Ex suscipit laborum velit atque, eaque dolorum sequi, eligendi laudantium fuga quos dolorem officia sunt totam. Quidem aspernatur vero vitae laborum quaerat dolorum. Consequatur a tempora adipisci qui enim doloribus sequi voluptate, quidem itaque tenetur aut voluptas obcaecati adipisci architecto beatae aliquam? Nemo cumque sequi accusamus nesciunt obcaecati id blanditiis, neque laborum tenetur eveniet, rerum enim voluptatem voluptate itaque eos ut sint officiis molestiae?</p>
                <p>Voluptate quis suscipit qui optio nulla unde veniam sed tempore itaque? Expedita optio amet, facere quia at consequatur reiciendis aperiam alias doloremque amet laudantium hic sunt, nulla voluptatem libero id veritatis molestiae ab in, totam dignissimos facere, accusantium voluptates mollitia quae iusto voluptas assumenda temporibus vel quod? Vero ipsa dolore impedit, animi laboriosam expedita similique impedit necessitatibus, repellat distinctio nobis amet voluptatem quae, expedita voluptas rerum?</p>
                <p>Ratione aliquid deleniti maxime dicta, fugit incidunt quam omnis ad maiores, blanditiis modi repellat cumque ut nemo. Sapiente sequi sint, illum fugiat eum non deserunt totam doloremque officiis, alias fugiat asperiores doloremque laudantium numquam iste, tempore illum rem quidem.</p>
                <p>Quam eum quia pariatur accusantium nesciunt, earum ducimus cupiditate doloribus voluptate fugiat reprehenderit esse obcaecati ex, corrupti dignissimos deserunt molestias tenetur minus, nam cum quaerat quidem, exercitationem iure ipsa vero neque quod iusto necessitatibus illo eos alias? Quae rem officiis accusantium ad expedita ratione modi tenetur reiciendis sint odio, eum animi voluptatem doloremque rem totam, sunt velit nobis blanditiis assumenda vel atque cupiditate nulla quo alias, sequi ullam nam deserunt eius labore nostrum hic tempore asperiores, dolorem repellendus expedita vel sit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h1>Section 2</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Temporibus tempore dignissimos quaerat quo quisquam delectus commodi nesciunt sed.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Notice how I only defined the `col-lg` size, if you do this, Bootstrap will assume anything below that size should use the full 12 columns by default, thus the sections will stack on mobile. I also removed one of the `section` elements and one of the `container` elements as they are not needed.

## [Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/qZeyqhcCjk)

Comment: I would like the height of each section to be 100% though. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at @dvLden answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: 100%;` from your `section` style.

Comment: I am trying to actually make each section to be the height of the window, so that is there deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your big problem: you are using multiple containers. What I would suggest doing is using just one container (and removing the section tags) like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h1>Section 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Ex suscipit laborum velit atque, eaque dolorum sequi, eligendi laudantium fuga quos dolorem officia sunt totam. Quidem aspernatur vero vitae laborum quaerat dolorum. Consequatur a tempora adipisci qui enim doloribus sequi voluptate, quidem itaque tenetur aut voluptas obcaecati adipisci architecto beatae aliquam? Nemo cumque sequi accusamus nesciunt obcaecati id blanditiis, neque laborum tenetur eveniet, rerum enim voluptatem voluptate itaque eos ut sint officiis molestiae?</p>
                    <p>Voluptate quis suscipit qui optio nulla unde veniam sed tempore itaque? Expedita optio amet, facere quia at consequatur reiciendis aperiam alias doloremque amet laudantium hic sunt, nulla voluptatem libero id veritatis molestiae ab in, totam dignissimos facere, accusantium voluptates mollitia quae iusto voluptas assumenda temporibus vel quod? Vero ipsa dolore impedit, animi laboriosam expedita similique impedit necessitatibus, repellat distinctio nobis amet voluptatem quae, expedita voluptas rerum?</p>
                    <p>Ratione aliquid deleniti maxime dicta, fugit incidunt quam omnis ad maiores, blanditiis modi repellat cumque ut nemo. Sapiente sequi sint, illum fugiat eum non deserunt totam doloremque officiis, alias fugiat asperiores doloremque laudantium numquam iste, tempore illum rem quidem.</p>
                    <p>Quam eum quia pariatur accusantium nesciunt, earum ducimus cupiditate doloribus voluptate fugiat reprehenderit esse obcaecati ex, corrupti dignissimos deserunt molestias tenetur minus, nam cum quaerat quidem, exercitationem iure ipsa vero neque quod iusto necessitatibus illo eos alias? Quae rem officiis accusantium ad expedita ratione modi tenetur reiciendis sint odio, eum animi voluptatem doloremque rem totam, sunt velit nobis blanditiis assumenda vel atque cupiditate nulla quo alias, sequi ullam nam deserunt eius labore nostrum hic tempore asperiores, dolorem repellendus expedita vel sit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1>Section 2</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Temporibus tempore dignissimos quaerat quo quisquam delectus commodi nesciunt sed.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Hopefully that helps!!!

Comment: If you are going to mark down this answer, I would appreciate knowing why. With all due respect, this code works as the OP wanted, so I would like to know why the downvote.

Comment: Thanks. I'd be interested to know why the down vote too, as I had thought of using a single container too but wasn't sure if that is the correct way to do it. Do I need to get rid of the section tags though? Couldn't they just go above the <div class="row"> tags?

Comment: I suppose you don't actually need to get rid of the section tags. I've never used them, but that certainly doesn't mean you shouldn't use them. I think that as long as you have the one container working, then you're fine and don't really need to worry about sections. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep 100% height on your sections, parents need to be 100% height as well.

```
html, body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then I'd suggest you to do following:

```
section {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    /* Define your preferrable minimum height, in case of any absolute elements */
    min-height: 340px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

[Working JS Fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/dvLden/xzjr23ny/2/)

Comment: I have already set the html & body height to 100% in my example. I can adjust the min-height value through trial & error, but some of my sections will contain dynamic content so I need to adjust the height automatically. What I would really like is something like "min-height: 100%", but it doesn't seem to work as I expect.

Comment: If your content is dynamic, make sure it has relative position to it. Then sure enough you can remove defined `height` and set `min-height: 100%`. I tested and it works as expected. Setting minimum height to `100%` and using height of all elements inside if height of `window` is less than expected height of content. So you're having some other bugs in your code for sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
section {
            /*remove height: 100%*/
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
```

Comment: Please explain the *why* behind this. Blobs of code with no description do not help.